# JavaScript Compiler Error - Facebook Pixel GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

Appreciate the help here. I removed my fb id for this post but it is in there in GTM.

Getting this error from GTM: Error at line 13, character 5: Parse error. '}' expected

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'blocked-out-my-id', { 
  em: '{{_email_}}', 
  // Data will be hashed automatically via a dedicated function in FB pixel
    ph: '{{_phone_number_}}',
    fn: '{{_FirstName_}}'
    ln: '{{_LastName_}}'
    ct: '{{_city_}}'
    st: '{{_state_}}'
    zp: '{{_zip_code_}}'
    country: '{{_country_}}'
    ge: '{{_gender_}}'
    db: '{{_dob_}}'
});
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=blocked-out-my-id&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: Please edit your question, make it readable by formatting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the function fbq you are using an object as a function parameter. This object contains key values pairs like ph: '{{*email*}}. Each of the key values pairs have to have a "," at the end, except the last one, like this:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'blocked-out-my-id', { 
  em: '{{_email_}}', 
  // Data will be hashed automatically via a dedicated function in FB pixel
    ph: '{{_phone_number_}}',
    fn: '{{_FirstName_}}',
    ln: '{{_LastName_}}',
    ct: '{{_city_}}',
    st: '{{_state_}}',
    zp: '{{_zip_code_}}',
    country: '{{_country_}}',
    ge: '{{_gender_}}',
    db: '{{_dob_}}'
});
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=blocked-out-my-id&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Also I'm not a 100% sure if you need the ' before the GTM Variables, most of them probably already contain string values.

Answer (score 0):

You need commas in the object. Specifically:

```
fbq('init', 'blocked-out-my-id', { 
  em: '{{_email_}}', 
  // Data will be hashed automatically via a dedicated function in FB pixel
    ph: '{{_phone_number_}}',
    fn: '{{_FirstName_}}',
    ln: '{{_LastName_}}',
    ct: '{{_city_}}',
    st: '{{_state_}}',
    zp: '{{_zip_code_}}',
    country: '{{_country_}}',
    ge: '{{_gender_}}',
    db: '{{_dob_}}'
});
```